# Generate phd html site using bookdown output from latex file

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, bookdown

Hum, i trying to understand how R Bookdown generate different html output to migrate easily my phd actually in latex on a html website.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true, natbib=true, isbn=false, doi=true, url=true, style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=999, sorting=nyt, refsection=chapter, hyperref]{biblatex}
```

As you can see, my thesis use biblatex with biber and natbib which permit me to use `\autocite` and `\autocites` command. I try multiple configuration to reuse this type of citation directly in markdown (and not [@key] or @key citation), without success.

I start with simple things in index.Rmd :

```
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
bibliography: [these.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
latex_engine: xelatex
citation_package: natbib
link-citations: yes
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
---

# Introduction

test my citation with \autocite{Pumain1997}.
```

`these.bib` contain this simple citation :

```
@article{Pumain1997,
author = {Pumain, Denise},
doi = {10.3406/spgeo.1997.1063},
issn = {0046-2497},
journal = {Espace g\'{e}ographique},
number = {2},
pages = {119--134},
title = {{Pour une th\'{e}orie \'{e}volutive des villes}},
url = {http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/spgeo\_0046-2497\_1997\_num\_26\_2\_1063},
volume = {26},
year = {1997}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that following rules are applied when rendering the `Rmd` file

1. `bookdown` specific commands will be translated by `bookdown` into the relevant LaTeX\HTML equivalent
2. `markdown` will be converted by `pandoc` into the relevant LaTeX\HTML equivalent
3. `LaTeX` (`HTML`) will be passed as is when the output format is `LaTeX` (`HTML`)
4. `LaTeX` (`HTML`) will be **ignored** when the output format is `HTML` (`LaTeX`)

Bottom line: use `@key` and `[@key]` in case you want to convert the document to both `LaTeX` and `HTML`